# what do the coefficients means in this matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices, image-processing

I found this [article](http://www.3dtv.at/knowhow/anaglyphcomparison_en.aspx) about creating anaglyphs through matrix multiplications, but I do not know what do the coefficents mean and do to the images? the 0,299,0,587 and the others can someone please explain me?, what do they do to the pixels? they set the pixel to zero?

Comment: It looks like a way of combining two monochromatic images to create one with more complex colors.  Each pixel in one image will have an (r,g,b) value, since there are two they are subscripted with a 1 and a 2.  Those matrices give the transformations that achieve the desired effect.  Hard to say where the specific values came from, probably there's some theory behind it, or maybe it's trial and error.  I'm just guessing.

Comment: thanks for answering I am trying to understand